# cmake cannot detect boost multiple installation

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I've previous boost installation from ubuntu repo which is 1.42 and its installed in `/usr/lib` Now I downloaded 1.52 and `./b2 install` that installed it in `/usr/local/lib`. now cmake is detecting 1.52 only and using include Path from `/usr/local/include` (which is 1.52) and using library directory `/usr/lib` (which is 1.42) and giving undefined reference errors.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(app)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.52 COMPONENTS filesystem program_options thread system serialization  REQUIRED)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(app list_of_cpp_files)
MESSAGE(STATUS "** Boost Include: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "** Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(app ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -O2")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-s")
endif()
```

even if I give a LIBRARY_PATH in CMakeLists.txt it still uses /usr/lib

What should be done now ? would I do a `booststrap.sh --prefix=/usr` but wont that make duplicate copies ? also Do I need change all symlinks manually ?

or I'll remove previous installation (1.42) from repo (apt-get) ? I cannot remove all because there are dependant packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing a `./bjam --layout=tagged install`